# Counting blanks in specific columns only

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a spreadsheet with Columns A to X. I want to audit whether inputs are made by counting the number of blanks. `COUNTBLANK` requires a range, but I've got columns that are mandatory to fill in and those that are non-mandatory. I've tried the following formula:

`=COUNTIF((A2, B2, F2, G2, H2, I2, J2, M2, N2, R2, S2, T2, V2, W2), "")` however I get a `#VALUE` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close:

```
=(A2="")+(B2="")+(F2="")+(G2="")+(H2="")+(I2="")+(J2="")+(M2="")+(N2="")+(R2="")+(S2="")+(T2="")+(V2="")+(W2="")
```

Comment: Columns C + D do not both have to be filled in, but at least one does, if I try to insert between B2 and F2 in your formula the following: `(IF(AND(C2="", D2="")))` I get a "the formula you typed contains an error" message, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"A2","B2","F2","G2","H2","I2","J2","M2","N2","R2","S2","T2","V2","W2"}),""))
```

or

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"A2:B2","F2:J2","M2:N2","R2:T2","V2:W2"}),""))
```

***Note :*** `INDIRECT` is a volatile function. For details on volatile function see [this](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm).